# Create Gate for Those Who Didn't Logged In

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to create a web page with Laravel. I have 3 types of users: users, members, admins. When someone register, they become a user. There are some restricted areas that can only be seen by members and admins. I can make it work those restrictions by using gates and @can in blade pages. But in some sections, I need to change the content. For instance, I want to show a banner to visitors and users, while show messages to members and admins in the very same div. In order to achieve that, I need help about 2 things, I guess:

1. How to create a gate for those who not logged in (let's call them visitors)? I tried the following alternatives for visitors, obviously none of them worked, so here I'm. If I display Auth::check() it returns 1 when I log in. I really don't understand why !=1 didn't work.

   ```
   Gate::define('visitors', function()
   {
       return Auth::user() == false;
       return Auth::user() == null;
       return Auth::check() == false;
       return Auth::check() == null;
       return Auth::check() != 1;
   });
   ```
2. How to merge visitors and users in one gate. Because in almost every single instance, visitors and users will be allowed to see the same content. I couldn't find any way to merge visitors and users. I tried pass two together like @can('visitors', 'users') ... and create two different gates with the same name like you see down below, and they didn't work. BTW the role_id of users is NULL. This is only data can be used to distinguish them from members and admins.

   ```
   Gate::define('visitors', function()
   {
       return Auth::user() == false;
   });
   Gate::define('visitors', function()
   {
       return is_null($user->role_id);
   });
   ```

Thanks for your helps.

EDIT: After 2 days straggling, it turned out the first part of my problem is very easy to solve. All I need is to wrap the content like so:

```
@geust
   <div>Something nice</div>
@endauth
```

Second part is still on. I need to use together @guest and @can('users').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answers and I want to share here for those who might be needed.

1. It turned out the answer was super easy. Just wrap your content like so.

   ```
   @geust
      <div>Something nice</div>
   @endauth
   ```
2. All I need is to create a logic to combine visitors and users

   ```
   @if (Auth::user() && is_null(Auth::user()->role_id) || Auth::guest()) {
       <div>Something nice</div>
   @endif
   ```

Bonus: I also managed to create a Custom Blade Directives. If you look for something like this, here is my example.

```
    //AppServiceProvider.php

    use Auth;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
    ...
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::if('EveryoneElse', function(){
            return Auth::user() && is_null(Auth::user()->role_id) || Auth::guest();
        });
    }
```

In blade template file.

```
    @EveryoneElse
        <div>Something nice</div>
    @endEveryoneElse
```

Answer (score 0):

The base of your problem was that Gate checks for the user to be logged in, so every gate for all users not logged in will always return false and never reach the defined callback. I faced this problem so i wanted to share this.